# How parse a multiple objects serialized in log with logstash and grok

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm parsing some log files with grok, but I have the following trace:

```
[es.org.some.Object[
 attr1=53212
 searchTags=[love, rock]
 ]]
[es.org.some.Object[
 attr1=54612
 searchTags=[love, peace, rock]
 ]]
```

I use the following expression for one:

```
%{DATA}\[%{JAVACLASS:Object}\[%{DATA}attr1=%{NUMBER:attr1}%{DATA}searchTags=%{DATA:searchTags}\]\]
```

but I have serverals... how can I parse this to have the next document:

```
Object1attr1: 53212
Object1searchTags: [love, rock]
Object2attr1: 54612
Object2searchTags: [love, peace, rock]
```

This is the best way to do this?

Thanks!!
Regards.

Comment: try to use multiline filter to create a line like Object1attr1: 53212 Object1searchTags: [love, rock] http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/multiline